# want to delete database file in my app. .tried with a program, that did not work

Tags: android-sqlite

I am trying to delete database table either programmatically or manually.
I created my own app which is under development.
My app is named SWULJ CT Conductor
But I do not find it under android/data/data folder with any com.xxx.xxx name format

code:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BusDetails.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "bus_details_table";
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NUMBER";
    public static final String COL_3 = "ROUTE";
    public static final String COL_4 = "CITY";
    public static final String COL_5 = "STATUS";

    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String myPath = TABLE_NAME + DATABASE_NAME;
        SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(new File(myPath));
        db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NUMBER TEXT,ROUTE TEXT,CITY TEXT,STATUS INTEGER)");
    }
```

It is the partial code for the databasehelper class
It is called from Activity like this:

```
public class GenerateQrCodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton imgButtonGenerateBulk;
    ImageButton imgButtonGenerateSingle;
    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    EditText edit;
    boolean flag = false;
    String data_bus_number=null;
    int ID_bus_number = -1;
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_generate_qr_code);
        myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        imgButtonGenerateBulk =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonGenerateBulk);
        imgButtonGenerateSingle =(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonGenerateSingle);
        edit =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bus_number);
.....
.....
```

I placed lines

```
 String myPath = TABLE_NAME + DATABASE_NAME;
 SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(new File(myPath));
```

But the old data from the database shows up. It is not deleted. Why? how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

done using the function->

```
public void deleteDatabase() {
        // Are you sure? (y/n)
        final SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        final File dbFile = new File(db.getPath());
        db.close();
        Toast.makeText(cntxt, "db deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        edit.setText("db deleted");
        if (dbFile.exists()) {
            SQLiteDatabase.deleteDatabase(dbFile);

        }
        //mOpenHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getContext());
    }
```